# How to access apache server running in virtualbox from host?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox

I want to access apache web server running in centos virtualbox. With my laptop connected in office lan network, I can access that webserver with bridged networking mode. But what I want to do is, access it when not connected to any network. Is this possible with virtual interfaces?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `port forwarding` feature accessible from the Network **advanced** settings of your virtual machine allows you to selectively expose a port of your virtual machine to your host.

This way, you can setup virtual machine port 80/tcp (http traffic) to be easily accessible from your localhost port 8080. Below is an exemple for this setting:

```
Name: webserver http
Protol: TCP
Host IP: 127.0.0.1
Host Port: 8080
Guest IP: 
Guest port: 80
```

Do the same with port 443/tcp (https traffic) if you serve it as well *(ex: 443 -> 8443)*.
Once done, you don't even need to bother with you virtual machine IP address to access its website. Just browse `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` and you are done.

Notes:

- It is fine to let `Guest IP` blank if it is assigned or known by VirtualBox itslef (I don't think this is the case with bridge mode, so I advise you to choose `Network Address Translation (NAT)`, `Internal Networking` or `Host-Only networking` options. [VirtualBox online documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes) explain key differences between networking options. *NAT will allow your virtual machine to connect the Internet for example, which you might like or dislike.*
- If you clears `Host IP` field, then other computers on you physical network will be able to connect this virtual machine web-server using your host IP address (ex: `http://192.168.1.xxx:8080`). This can help you setting up a unique configuration for your both use cases and even improve the security of your virtual machine by not exposing all its open ports to real networks.
- You can not easily use local port 80 for this forward since ports below 1024 require privileges. Hence the common choice of 8080 in such case.

Comment: thank you for your simple answer, on Linux host we only got port forwarding in NAT option (vbox   5.1.28)